# Fetching data from async api call using react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having problem with an api call in my **React Redux** project. Here's the code snippet from the project.

**poiAction.js**

```
export function poiSuccess(pois) {
  // The log detail is below
  console.log("POI: ", pois);
  return {
      pois,
      type: POI_FETCH_SUCCESS
  };
}
export function poiFetch(pois) {
  return {
    pois,
    type: POI_FETCH_ATTEMPT
  };
}

export function fetchPoi(token) {
  return dispatch =>
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:9090/poi',
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token
      },
    })
    .then((pois) =>{
      // let poi = pois.data[0];
      // console.log("POIS: ", pois.data[0]);
      dispatch(poiSuccess(pois));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw(error);
    })
}
```

**console log output:**

[image: console.log("POI:", pois)]

**poiReducer.js**

```
export default function poi(state = [], action){
  switch(action.type){
    case POI_FETCH_ATTEMPT:
    return state;
    case POI_FETCH_FAILED:
    return state;
    case POI_FETCH_SUCCESS:
    // The console log output is same as poiAction
    console.log("Reducer: ", action.pois);
    return [action.pois, ...state];
    break;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**The console log output is same as poiAction**

**Root Reducer**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  LoginReducer,
  PoiReducer
});
```

The component to display the list from the api call:

**Dashboard.js**

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      poi: '',
      token: null
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    this.setState({token});
    this.props.actions.fetchPoi(token);
  }
  render() {
    console.log("POIS: ", this.props.pois);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  pois: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("State: ", state);
  return {
    pois: state.poiReducer
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(poiAction, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

Here `this.props.pois` is `undefined` and the value of `state` from `mapStateToProps` is:

[image: state value]

What am I missing? How do I access the list that's returning from the api call ?

Thanks

Comment: As for me you have to return ->  `function(dispatch){ axios.get().then( //dispatch)}` instead of `return dispatch()...`. Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/oviava/react-redux-axios-example/blob/master/src/actions/actions.js) example

Comment: @TheReason I'm using `thunk` and `redux-promise` as the middleware.

Answer (score 1):

When you combine your reducers, you do this

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  LoginReducer,
  PoiReducer
});
```

which means

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  LoginReducer : LoginReducer,
  PoiReducer : LoginReducer
});
```

And that's not what you want.

it should be

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginReducer : LoginReducer,
  poiReducer : LoginReducer
});
```

Also, for some reason, you got a rootReducer inside your root reducer, which is a little weird.

So the way to access to poiReducer would be

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("State: ", state);
  return {
    pois: state.rootReducer.poiReducer
  };
}
```